# Limit send_keys to specific number of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to make a bot to automatically send Instagram messages to a specific person. I'm having trouble with Instagram's direct message character limit; right now it sends keys from a text file. Once it hits Instagram's character limit the program keeps trying to type and nothing happens. I want it to stop at a specified limit and press enter to send the message, then continue typing again.

```
# Loops through the text file typing out each character

for character, words in enumerate(message):
    message_box.send_keys(words)

# Supposed to realize when the 500th character is sent, press the enter key to send the message on Instagram

    if character == 500:
        message_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Edit: I'm thinking now that send_keys() isn't sending characters one by one, meaning the count is only going to be 1 not 500.  Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# This iterates over the message text file and chunks it into 500 character sections  

for group in chunked(message, 500):
#Types out each chunk
    message_box.send_keys(group)
# Presses send button on instagram       
    send()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```py
limit = 500  # your limit to no. of characters

for character, words in enumerate(message[:limit]):
  message_box.send_keys(words)  

message_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Sadly, produces the same result